# Windows Convert Folder to Floppy IMG?

Tags: windows, floppy

I have a folder on my computer whose contents contain a program that originated from a floppy.  The Windows computer I am currently running does not have a floppy drive.

Is there a program which can convert the contents of a given folder to a floppy IMG or IMA file? All of the programs that I see require the files to originate from a floppy before it will package them into a IMG file.

This file should not be bootable.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: of course, there are software for virtual cd drives. I don't know about whether virtual cd drives are writable, I suppose they are,  and virtual floppy drives probably are writable.  You'll then have an A:\>  another option is to get an external usb floppy drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Virtaul Floppy Drive](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vfd/).

However, you will need some efforts to install it on Windows 7 SP1 x64.

**EDIT:** It does not work on x64 machines since the driver is meant only for 32 bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/download.htm) (32/64-bit versions available, portable version as well, works fine on Win7 and probably Win8 too).

Comment: The 64-bit download on that site was flagged by Chrome as containing a virus.